# AutoHotKey Internet Explorer Object Retrieve Span tag Text

Tags: html, internet-explorer, autohotkey

From the target page I found:

`<legend><span class="labelOnMed">Plan name:</span> <span class="textOnMed">myCompanyName</span></legend>`

Is there any way to retrieve or extract the text within a particular `<span>` tag?

```
Loop %numberOfLink%
    {
        If (Links[A_Index-1].InnerText == cin) {
            Links[A_Index-1].Click()
            IELoad(wb)

            planID := wb.document.getElementsByTagName("textOnMed")
            MsgBox, %planID%
        }
    }
```

And I also tried:

```
planID := wb.document.getElementsByTagName("textOnMed")
planString := planID.value
MsgBox, %planID%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
planID := wb.document.getElementsByClassname("textOnMed")[0].innerText
```